# angular routerLink attribute click is not working with nwjs

Tags: angular, nwjs

angular routerLink attribute click is not working with nwjs

executed nw . 
the app was launched as desktop app.
When I click on the element which has routerLink attribute, it doesn't do anything. stays on same view.

Navigation is not happening.

Can help please..
how will I have navigation support of angular app via nwjs(desktop) app

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with nwjs, but if you can get a console outpot this might help: For debugging the routing, you can [implement temporary](https://angular.io/guide/router) this in your module.ts:

```
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
```

This will show in your browser console what is happening when the app tries to navigate.